# SQL Server 2017 microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-x64-driver-freezing-using-open-rowset

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2017, openrowset

I am using the openrowset feature to do a bulk insert

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0; Database=\\mylocation_file_manager\',[Sheet1$])
```

this query works fine for a while but breaks unpredictably and only solution to make it work again is restarting the SQL service

Does anyone know what could be wrong with this ?

Comment: I have the same problem with sql server 2014, oledb driver 16.0 x64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

changed my solution and started using

BULK INSERT @Table_Name  FROM  @File_Path
  WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR='@!', ROWTERMINATOR='!', FIRSTROW=2 , CODEPAGE='ACP' )

working seamlessly without any issues